# rejected by UIFileSharingEnabled key set to true

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I've got rejected my recent update on iPhone app and it says:

*"When file sharing is enabled, the entire Documents folder is used for file sharing. Files that that are not intended for user access via the file sharing feature should be stored in another part of your application's bundle. If your application does not require the file sharing feature, the UIFileSharingEnabled key in the Info.plist should not be set to true."*

I don't have any data which is not supposed to backup via iTunes. So, in this case, how to make a change or appeal to pass the review?

Comment: Hi @Sanghoon, did my answer answer your question?

Comment: Did you explain to the review team? What did they say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to pass Apple's review without rejection and still set UIFileSharingEnabled = true.
It was very helpful to see the how to from raywenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app.
The key is making the sharing data simple, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980303/apple-not-allow-the-app-share-document-directory-data-directly-to-user-uifiles). This part might be relevant for your situation:

> When file sharing is enabled, the entire Documents folder is used for
>   file sharing. Files that are not intended for user access via the file
>   sharing feature should be stored in another part of your application's
>   bundle.

Only store user relevant documents in the /Documents folder. For other non-temporary files, use /Library/Application Support instead (or /Library/Preferences).

Comment: What if you respect your users' freedom to view and change files stored on the device they own, and don't want to get in their way? I know that's what jailbreaking is for, but not everyone is on an iOS version that can be jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue.

In my case I was able to pass Apple's review by changing following line in **Info.plist** from

> ```
> <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
> <string>true</string>
> ```

to

> ```
> <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
> <true/>
> ```

Comment: isnt that the same thing?

Comment: On the first sight it is, but for me only the second one worked in the end.